# Migration from MySQL to Oracle generates empty tables

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-sql-developer, oracle-xe

I'm using SQL Developer to migrate a database from MySQL 5.7 to Oracle 18c XE. The problem is that the tables are generated but empty, even though I'm specifying that the data should move online. I also looked at the scripts, and there's no data either.

What I see in the log is `DataMove.DISABLE_CONSTRAINTS_FAILED`. How to fix this?

These are the migration options:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution: create a user/schema in Oracle that has the same name as the database you want to import.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any *errors* as part of the process?

Are the tables being created within a particular schema (a.k.a. account)?
If so, has that account been given a *quota* in which it is allowed to store any data?

Good Old Oracle Database - just because you can *create* a table doesn't mean you can put anything *into* it.

```
create tablespace aardvark_ts ... ; 

create user aardvark identified by 'really-really-secure-password'; 
grant create session to aardvark ; 

alter user aardvark quota unlimited on aardvark_ts ; 

grant create table to aardvark ;
```